# Как определить, что приложение в андроид свернули?

Tags: android, activity

Добрый день!

У меня следующая ситуация, играет фоновая музыка. 
Во время переходов между несколькими activity музыка должна продолжать играть, но если приложение свернули, с любого activity, музыка должна быть на паузе. Когда развернули приложение то музыка должна продолжиться играть.

События `onPause`, `onStop` отрабатывают как при сворачивании приложения так и между переходами activity.

Comment: ваше приложение использует переворачивание экрана? То есть вертикальную и горизонтальную ориентации?

Comment: только горизонтальную ориентацию.

Answer (score 1):

Через Service можно сделать так:

1.Создаем класс:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
MediaPlayer player;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
   // Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ra3);//устанавливаем мелодию
    player.setLooping(true); // зацикливаем
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
 //   Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    player.stop();
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    player.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
}
```

2.Прописываем в манифесте сервис:

```
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />
```

3.В самом коде стартуем:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

Останавливаем:

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

4.Проверить выполнение сервиса:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

5.Добавляете флаг типа Boolean, Когда сами вызываете переход в другую активити ставите true. В самом событии (onPause, onStop) проверяете этот флаг. И уже в зависимости от результата либо приостанавливаете, либо продолжает играть.

Answer (score 0):

Service для проигрывания музыки используй.

В `Service` делаешь переменную `countActivity` и метод `setCount`. При создании первого активити запускаешь сервис, передаешь значение `1` и при переходе во второе активити, перед стартом активити, увеличиваешь счетчик на `1`, а при срабатывании метода `onStop`, уменьшаешь `countActivity` на `1`. Если `countActivity==0`, останавливаешь музыку.

Comment: В Service делаешь переменную countActivity и метод setCount при создании первого активити запускаешь сервис передаешь значение 1, и переходе во второе активити, перед стартом активити увеличиваешь счетчик на 1, а при срабатывании метода onStop уменьшаешь countActivity на 1, если countActivity==0, останавливаешь музыку, где то так. Возможно есть и другой способ не знаю.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее ваше решение. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п. Подробный и качественный ответ поможет гораздо большему количеству людей, столкнувшихся с подобной проблемой.

Answer (score 0):

Если используете только одну ориентацию, тогда можно паузу выполнять в методе onSaveInstanceState(), а обратно воспроизводить в методе onRestoreInstanceState(). Переопределите оба эти метода в ваших Activity.